# layer ordering in Openlayers 3 (z-index)

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a mapping application where I have layer tree. When I click the layers I want the latest clicked layer on top of all the layers.

This works fine when i click the layers one by one. But if I switch off the layer and switch it on again then it doesn't appear on top.

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Any help guys :)

I have attached the functions that I am using in my application:

```js
//this is the function when a checkbox is checked.
var AddLayerToSettings = function(layerName){
  var num = layerVisibleCount();
  if (layerName == "AH42Road"){
    if(num==0){//checking if there are any layers added before or not
      map.getLayers().insertAt(1, road_AH42);
    }else{
      layerOrderingWhenClicked();                   
    }
    $("#AH42RoadLayer").show();                 
    $( ".column" ).prepend( $( "#AH42RoadLayer" ) );                                        
  }

  if(layerName == "districtsboundary"){
    if(num==0){//checking if there are any layers added before or not
      map.getLayers().insertAt(1, districtsBoundary);
    } else {
      layerOrderingWhenClicked();                   
    }
    $("#districtsboundarylayer").show();
    $( ".column" ).prepend( $( "#districtsboundarylayer" ) );
  }
  if(layerName == "developmentregions"){
    if(num==0){//checking if there are any layers added before or not
      map.getLayers().insertAt(1, developmentRegions);
    }else{
      layerOrderingWhenClicked();                   
    }
    $("#developmentregionslayer").show();
    $( ".column" ).prepend( $( "#developmentregionslayer" ) );
  } 
};

var layerOrderingWhenClicked = function(){
  var zIndex = 1;
  for(i=0; i<selectedLayers.length; i++){
    if(selectedLayers[i] == "districtsBoundary"){
      map.getLayers().insertAt(zIndex, districtsBoundary);          
    }
    if(selectedLayers[i] == "road_AH42"){
      map.getLayers().insertAt(zIndex, road_AH42);
    }
    if(selectedLayers[i] == "developmentRegions"){
      map.getLayers().insertAt(zIndex, developmentRegions);
    }
    zIndex++;
  }
};
```

Comment: Why aren't you using layer.setVisible() to make the layers visible or not?

Comment: In your code you have two different names for a layer `AH42Road` and `road_AH42` and `districtsboundary` !== `districtsBoundary` and `developmentregions` !== `developmentRegions` (note case!). This is possibly one reason why it's screwing up. In any event, the code for each named layer is very similar, you should be able to simplify it...

Comment: This example can help you: http://acanimal.github.io/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter02_02_layer_stack.html It works using `setAt` method instead the `insertAt`.

Comment: @EricSonaron: the example you quoted is using setAt because it's just swapping two layers around. It's not clear from OP's code whether he should be removing the layer from the map before inserting it at a different index.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but part of your problem is inconsistent layer naming.
Here's a rewrite where the methods are more independent of the data....

```js
var specialLayers = {
  "road_AH42": { 
    "layer" : road_AH42,
    "id": "#AH42RoadLayer"
  },
  "districts_AH42": { 
    "layer" : districtsBoundary,
     "id": "#districtsBoundarylayer"
  },
  "developmentRegions": { 
    "layer" : developmentRegions, 
     "id": "#developmentregionslayer"
  }
};

var AddLayerToSettings = function(layerName){
  var layerData;
  var num = layerVisibleCount();
  if (specialLayers.hasOwnProperty( layerName)) {
    layerData = specialLayers[layerName];
    if (num == 0) {
       map.getLayers().insertAt(1, layerData.layer);
    } else {
      layerOrderingWhenClicked();
    }
    $(layerData.id).show();                 
    $( ".column" ).prepend( $( layerData.id ) );      
  }
};

var layerOrderingWhenClicked = function(){
  var zIndex = 1;
  var i, layerData;
  // selectedLayers scope unknown here...
  for(i=0; i<selectedLayers.length; i++){
    if (specialLayers.hasOwnProperty( selectedLayers[i]) {
      layerData = specialLayers[selectedLayers[i]];
      map.getLayers().insertAt(zIndex, layerData.layer);          
    }
    zIndex++;
  }
};
```

As you haven't shown the rest of the code, I am not sure whether you are inserting a layer that may be already in the map; please check.